# Shell Поиск файлов функцией find

Tags: shell

Знаю как искать файлы find ищу по содержимому, пример:

```
find . -type f -name "*.php*" -exec grep -i -H "base64_decode(" {} \; > find.txt
```

как сделать так чтобы добавить в файлы исключения, например чтобы сразу убрать из результатов файлы которые не подходят.а также как добавить в find больше выражений для поиска или например если добавить нельзя, то вызывая каждый раз новый find, как сделать чтобы результаты писали в один и тот же файл без перезаписи, а добавляя в конец то что найдено?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы без перезаписи, то это

> find [...всё что угодно...] >> result.txt

А если нужен сложный поиск, с применением регулярных выражений (ваш случай), то надо делать примерно так:

> find . -type f -name "*.php*" | grep-i -H "base64_decode(" {} \; >> find.txt

Где после команды grep должно быть регулярное выражение для поиска. Смысл в том, что вывод find нужно фильтровать grep'ом, а не корячиться в нём самом. В общем, читайте man grep, там всё написано!

Comment: спасиб)!!!

Comment: поставь ему ответ!